# impala shell, shell command with capitals

Tags: python, shell, escaping, impala

I've got a lot of commands running in impala shell, in the middle of them I now have a need to run a python script. The script itself is fine when run from outside the impala shell.

When I run from within the impala shell using ! or "shell" (documentation found [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_shell_commands.html)) it changes the commands to be fully lower case.

The path to the script itself would be something like this: **/home/DOMAIN_USERS/somemorefolders/python/script.py**

so in my impala shell I'm running: `!/home/DOMAIN_USERS/somemorefolders/python/script.py`

the error I get back is

> sh: /home/domain_users/somemorefolders/python/script.py: No such file
>   or directory

Is there any way to force it to not make it into lower case? I've tried putting both single & double quotes round the path but that makes no difference.

I guess if there's no way I'll have to come out of the impala shell, run the python bit then go back in. Its just a bit more work when I figured the "shell" command in the impala shell is there for that exact benefit.

Comment: Try !pwd in impala-shell. Depending on what your current working directory is, you might want to move the script around and use relative paths.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by a known bug [IMPALA-4664](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-4664).

A workaround is to leave a space after "!".  Can you try this (note the space):

! /home/DOMAIN_USERS/somemorefolders/python/script.py

Comment: I've just got round to testing this with the space (as what I've put below worked) so sorry for the delay. It still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@BoboDarph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8085234/bobodarph) for help in getting there.
I was able to use `!~/somemorefolders/python/script.py` as I could get there from my home directory.

I still think it's a bit shortsighted of impala to force things into lower case but there you go.